# How do I re position the google map infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I re position the infowindow in a google map?

I would like the window to open under the marker with the little indent facing up towards to the marker.

Here is my code I thought the pixeloffset would be the option to change but not sure. When I adjust the y to 70 it shows up below the marker but how do I change the indent to flip around?

```js
$infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: "Drag the map to re-center location",
  pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 70), // want the window to open underneathe with the indent facing up
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are looking for is not (currently) supported by the native [`google.maps.InfoWindow`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#InfoWindow).  You can create a [feature request in the issue tracker for the Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/).

For something that would work now, [InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/) might do what you are looking for, see the [example in the documentation](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/infobox-basic.html)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var secheltLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47216, -123.76307);

  var myMapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: secheltLoc,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var theMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myMapOptions);


  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: theMap,
    draggable: true,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47216, -123.76307),
    visible: true
  });

  var boxText = document.createElement("div");
  boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: white; padding: 5px; text-align: center;";
  boxText.innerHTML = "Drag the map to re-center location";

  var myOptions = {
    content: boxText,
    disableAutoPan: false,
    maxWidth: 0,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
    zIndex: null,
    boxStyle: {
      background: "url('http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/tipbox.gif') no-repeat",
      opacity: 0.75,
      width: "280px"
    },
    closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px",
    closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif",
    infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
    isHidden: false,
    pane: "floatPane",
    enableEventPropagation: false
  };

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
    ib.open(theMap, this);
  });

  var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);

  ib.open(theMap, marker);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
<p>
  This example shows the "traditional" use of an InfoBox as a replacement for an InfoWindow.
```

Comment: yes infobox does it but that's not infowindow! plus i would need additional libs which  I DON'T WANT TO USE.

Comment: how do I change the width and pixeloffset to adjust to text that says "Drag the map to re-center location"?